# Using RMarkdown and Flextable to produce a table in Word with the property 'Allow row to break across pages'

Tags: r-markdown, flextable

I use Flextable with R Markdown to produce tables in word documents.

I am looking for a way to produce the table so that when it is in Word the table property 'Allow row to break across pages' is turned on. I have tried to do this by modifying the template document which defines the text styles for R Markdown but I cant get this to work.

Is there a way to modify the code (example below) so the resulting table in Word has the property 'Allow row to break across pages' turned on?

````
```{r table}
data <- iris[c(1:3, 51:53, 101:104),]
library(flextable)
data<-regulartable(data)
data
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a chunk option `ft.split=TRUE`:

````
```{r ft.split=TRUE}
library(flextable)
data<-regulartable(head(iris))
data
```
````